# while using openweather.org api using for temperature and weather it shows an keyerror

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, dictionary, openweathermap

In my voice assistant project, I want to set a forecast. Hence I am using api key from openweather.org and my code is as below

```
import requests
from os import *

api_address = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=bfbe606c8d661478b8132b49eee8051a"
json_data = requests.get(api_address).json()
# json_data = json_data.json()

def temp():
    temperature = round(json_data['main']['temp']-273.1)
    return temperature

def des():
    description = json_data["weather"][0]["description"]
    return description

print(temp())
print(des())
```

But here problem is console shows an error about 'keyerror':

```
line 9, in temp
    temperature = round(json_data['main']['temp']-273.1)

KeyError: 'main'
```

please suggest me any solution which can took out me from this problem.

Comment: Are you sure there's a main property?

Comment: Have you debugged your code and look at your json_data structure? When I tried your code, I got the 401 error. Seems like your API-key is not working yet. They suggest waiting a couple of hours before using it. Please read here: https://openweathermap.org/faq#error401

Comment: I think you need to use json.load() before trying to access the data inside

Comment: Come to think of it, you should probably not post your API-key here, since it's linked to your personal account on Openweather. Any requests done with that API-key, will be tracked down to you. I suggest that you delete that key and create a new one.

Comment: yes this is main property

Comment: {
     "coord": {
       "lon": 145.77,
       "lat": -16.92
     },
     "weather": [
       {
         "id": 802,
         "main": "Clouds",
         "description": "scattered clouds",
         "icon": "03n"
       }
     ],
     "base": "stations",
     "main": {
       "temp": 300.15,
       "pressure": 1007,
       "humidity": 74,
       "temp_min": 300.15,
       "temp_max": 300.15
     },
     "visibility": 10000,
     "wind": {
       "speed": 3.6,
       "deg": 160
     },
I showed a part of api doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creator of Open-Meteo here. You could use the Open-Meteo API which does not require an API key:

```py
import requests
from os import *

api_address = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?latitude=52.52&longitude=13.41&current_weather=true"
json_data = requests.get(api_address).json()

def temp():
    temperature = json_data['current_weather']['temperature']
    return temperature

def des():
    description = json_data["current_weather"]["weathercode"]
    return description

print(temp())
print(des())
```

Output:

```
12.4
2
```

Please note to put in your correct latitude and longitude to get the forecast for your location

Comment: this is really worked. So thank you.